# How to compare user input with rules and facts?

Tags: prolog

i want to build this solution:
Prolog ask me for my preferred weather dates and show me the best match (not the exact match, depends on degree).

For example:
Given list

```
Monday = [hot, sunny, 30] //30 degree
Tuesday = [hot, cloudy, 25]
Wednesday = [hot, sunny, 25]
```

Question 1:
Do you like it hot or cold?
Answer1: hot

Question 2:
Do you like it sunny or cloudy?
Answer2: sunny

Question 3:
What is the minimum of temperature?
Answer3: 22

**-> Now Prolog should answers this:**

The best day for your vacation is:

```
Monday = [hot, sunny, 30] 
Wednesday = [hot, sunny, 25]
```

**My Code:**

```
/* Ask all Questions */
go: -
  q1,
  q2,
  q3.

/* Questions 1 */
q1: -
  abolish(q1 / 1), /* clear clause, if q1 is used by user manually */
  write('Do you like it hot or cold?'),
  read(Q1),
  asserta(q1(Q1)).

/*same for Q2 and Q3*/
```

At the end I have this:

```
  q1(hot)
q2(sunny)
q3(22)
```

I can compare this to a list, so I have [hot, sunny, 22] (don't know why but I can do this)

Now i really don't know how to compare the pre-lists with my answers. Don't know to compare the temperature.

**Can anybody help me with an example? I really want to learn about Prolog, but I don't know how to handle with this problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way you could do it. I have changed the representation to facts of type day rather than lists.

```
day(monday,hot,sunny,30).
day(tuesday,hot, cloudy,25).
day(wednesday,hot,sunny,25).

go:-
    q1(X),
    q2(Y),
    q3(Z),
    day(Day,X,Y,Z1),
    Z1 >=Z, %this will back track and find other results if the first one found fails
    print([Day,X,Y,Z1]). %this can be made more pretty if you wish.


q1(X):-
   write('Do you like it hot or cold?'),
   read(X).

q2(Y):- write('Do you like it sunny or cloudy?'),
  read(Y).

q3(Z):- write('What is the minimum temperature?'),
  read(Z).
```